# Make this loop simple (print Letter J in Java using loop)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I try to print letter D on console, but I couldn't help the code is longer than my expectation. Could you help me.... there are another way to reduce this code? Thank you.
This is my code:

```
public class LetterD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i = 1;i<=14;i++){
         for(int j = 1;j<=4;j++) System.out.print("*");
         if(i == 1 || i==14) for(int k = 1;k<=7;k++) System.out.print("*");
         if(i == 2 || i==13) for(int k = 1;k<=9;k++) System.out.print("*");
         if(i == 3 || i==12){
             for(int k = 1;k<=6;k++) System.out.print(" ");
             for(int l = 7;l<=10;l++) System.out.print("*");
         }
         if(i==4||i==11){
             for(int k = 1;k<=7;k++) System.out.print(" ");
             for(int l = 8;l<=11;l++) System.out.print("*");
         }
         if(i==5||i==10){
             for(int k = 1;k<=8;k++) System.out.print(" ");
             for(int l = 9;l<=12;l++) System.out.print("*");
         }
         if(i==6||i==9){
             for(int k = 1;k<=9;k++) System.out.print(" ");
             for(int l = 10;l<=13;l++) System.out.print("*");
         }
         if(i==7||i==8){
             for(int k = 1;k<=10;k++) System.out.print(" ");
             for(int l = 11;l<=14;l++) System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
    }
}
```

The output will be like this one:

```
***********
*************
****      ****
****       ****
****        ****
****         ****
****          ****
****          ****
****         ****
****        ****
****       ****
****      ****
*************
***********
```

Comment: Looks like you already print the letter well. Is the length of the code your only problem?

Comment: I edited my question...Yep, the length my code is my problem. Are you have another suggestion for me to reduce the code? Or this is just the one solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper methods simply your code a lot:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAsterisks(11, true);
    printAsterisks(13, true);
    for(int i = 6; i < 10; i++){
        printSpaced(i);
    }
    for(int i = 10; i > 5; i--){
        printSpaced(i);
    }
    printAsterisks(13, true);
    printAsterisks(11, true);
}

static void printSpaced(int spaces){
    printAsterisks(4, false);
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    printAsterisks(4, true);
}

static void printAsterisks(int n, boolean newLine){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    if(newLine){
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the most obvious way to make the code shorter is to draw the central part of the letter in a loop, like so:

```
public class LetterD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 1;i<=14;i++) {
            for(int j = 1;j<=4;j++) System.out.print("*");
            if(i == 1 || i==14) for(int k = 1;k<=7;k++) System.out.print("*");
            if(i == 2 || i==13) for(int k = 1;k<=9;k++) System.out.print("*");
            if (i > 2 && i < 13) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10 - Math.abs(i - 7.5); j++) System.out.print(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, i forget math class in java. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of strings to represent individual rows of the letter D "pixels" and iterate in your for-loop over it. If you want to go real fancy, you can encode "pixel" rows as integers and decode them using bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop?

```
System.out.println("***********"
               + "\n*************"
               + "\n****      ****"
               + "\n****       ****"
               + "\n****        ****"
               + "\n****         ****"
               + "\n****          ****"
               + "\n****          ****"
               + "\n****         ****"
               + "\n****        ****"
               + "\n****       ****"
               + "\n****      ****"
               + "\n*************"
               + "\n***********")
```

---

You don't see hello world programs like this, do you?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if(i == 0)       System.out.print("H");
    else if(i == 1)  System.out.print("e");
    else if(i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 9)
                     System.out.print("l");
    else if(i == 4 || i == 7)
                     System.out.print("o");
    else if(i == 5)  System.out.print(" ");
    else if(i == 6)  System.out.print("w");
    else if(i == 8)  System.out.print("r");
    else if(i == 10) System.out.print("d");
    else             System.out.print("!");
}
```

Comment: I want to try train my logic using Java control statement (if and for). Your answer is right but..

Comment: Eric, now I want to upvote your answer once again, alas SO won't let me :)

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution with a single loop:

```
public static void printD(int size, int currentStep, boolean dir) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size + currentStep; i++) {
        if (currentStep > size / 10) {
            if (i > size / 3 && i < size + currentStep - (size / 3)) {
                System.out.print("-");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (currentStep < size / 2 && dir) {
        printD(size, currentStep + 1, true);
    } else {
        if (currentStep > 0) {
            printD(size, currentStep - 1, false);
        }
    }
}
```

And to print something similar to your result call `printD(12, 0, true);`

Comment: thank you so much. So, the solution is recursion.

Comment: now try this with the letter G :)

Comment: @afni It's not the only solution

Comment: @tibtof there are another way?

Comment: @afni user1096188 just gave you another solution :)

Comment: you just lost yourself some reputation :D

Comment: @rotsch I don't deserve reputation if I cannot write G :)